# Код ответа веб-сервера 204 вместо 200

Tags: javascript, веб-сервер

подскажите пожалуйста. почему может возвращаться код ответа от веб-сервера 204 вместо 200? например, браузер запрашивает страницу, на странице - подгружается javascript, который содержит редирект. но получается так, что когда браузер идет по ссылке этого редиректа, ему сервер отдает не страницу с кодом 200, а пустой ответ с кодом 204. почему такое может происходить? извините, внятно объяснить ситуацию не получилось. 
причем, javascript на страницу подгружается из другого приложения (с другого сервера). кроссдоменно.

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP/1.0 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) 204 означает «нет ответа» и возвращается, когда сервер получил запрос, но ему нечего сообщить в ответ, а клиент должен оставаться на предыдущей странице (не менять вид страницы). Используется, в основном, чтобы принять данные от скрипта, в то же время не меняя документ.

> No Response 204
>
> Server has received the request but
> there is no information to send back,
> and the client should stay in the same
> document view. This is mainly to allow
> input for scripts without changing the
> document at the same time.

**Upd**. более актуальный [HTTP/1.1 RFC 2616](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) пишет примерно то же, подробнее:

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the
> request but does not need to return an
> entity-body, and might want to return
> updated metainformation. The 
> response MAY include new or updated
> metainformation in the form of 
> entity-headers, which if present
> SHOULD be associated with the 
> requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it
> SHOULD NOT change its document view 
> from that which caused the request to
> be sent. This response is    primarily
> intended to allow input for actions to
> take place without    causing a change
> to the user agent's active document
> view, although    any new or updated
> metainformation SHOULD be applied to
> the document    currently in the user
> agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a
> message-body, and thus is always 
> terminated by the first empty line
> after the header fields.